# What are the best books to study Phonology at an introductory level?

Tags: phonology, reference-request

I'm looking for a good introduction to phonology book with good examples of diverse languages.

Answer (score 3):

More on the phonetics than phonology side, but Ladefoged’s [*Vowels and Consonants*](https://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1444334298,descCd-buy.html) is very accessible and the author is a standard reference.  From there you should be able to follow [*The Sounds of the World’s Languages*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/The+Sounds+of+the+World%27s+Languages-p-9780631198154) for discussion on a wide range of languages.

I’d also like to recommend, as a companion to whatever you choose, Catford’s [*A Practical Introduction to Phonetics*](https://global.oup.com/ushe/product/a-practical-introduction-to-phonetics-9780199246359?cc=de&lang=en&).  This is an unusual book; it’s very short but intense, because it’s all about practical exercises to get you to *perform* sounds of all kinds—including the more exotic things like ejectives and whatnot.  It will give you an entirely different kind of hand-on knowledge about the possibilities of speech.  Be warned that, while working on it, you *will* catch yourself unconsciously making funny noises in public and attracting attention.

Comment: Second the recommendation for Catford. I always told my students that when they study phonetics, they must give up all hope of personal dignity. This is why we should probably teach phonetics in the introductory grades, when the children can enjoy it.

Comment: As a phonetics book, certainly, but why as a phonology book?

Comment: @user6726 I assumed OP is using "phonology" broadly to mean phonetics+phonology.  If the question is actually about phonological theories specifically, then I'm not qualified to recommend textbooks.

Comment: Unless someone knows phonetics rather well already, phonological theory is impenetrable. it would be like describing paintings while ignoring color.

Answer (score 1):

[Murderous_squirrel's recommendations](https://old.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/8iahqm/i_emailed_noam_chomsky_and_he_responded_holy_shit/dyq8tam/)

*Phonology: A formal introduction* by Charles Reiss and Alan Bale (2018)
*An Introduction to Phonetics and Phonology* by John Clark, Colin Yallop, (Blackwell textbook series, 2006).

See our [Reading List](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993).

> ### Phonology
>
> - Philip Carr. *Phonology*. (1993).
> - Bruce Hayes. *Introductory Phonology*. (2009).
> - John Jensen. *Principles of Generative Phonology*. (2004).
> - Paul de Lacy. *The Cambridge Handbook of Phonology*. (2007).
> - David Odden - *Introducing Phonology*. (2005).

Comment: I'd add Gussenhoven & Jacobs there. It's probably most accessible.

Comment: @Nardog Please add it to https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993.